# how to appear a window(div) on the site main page that site won't be clickable

Tags: html, css

I want to show a div with some buttons ,first time my site loads and I want that the site become not usable until that div closes with one of its buttons (like when you choose an image in image.google.com and after that you see the selected picture with the site it extracted from behind it but that site is a little dark and just like a photo of the site)

*I hope I could ask what I meant and if the structure of sentences are wrong I'm really sorry because english is my second language*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="dialog">
    Close me to see anything else
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
#overlay{
position:fixed;
z-index:9999;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
#dialog{
width:200px;
height:100px;
margin-left:-100px;
margin-top:-50px;
left:50%;
top:50%;
position:absolute;
background-color:#ffffff;
border:1px solid #666;
padding:20px;
}
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/MqVMr/

Here is an updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/MqVMr/1/

Full Screen http://jsfiddle.net/MqVMr/1/show/

Comment: thanks for your response but I need the #overlay be like a photo with no ability to scroll or click on its different parts, can you help about this?

Comment: oh yes thanks the problem was the version of my jquery it should be 7+

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a floating div that absolutely positioned with a high z-index.  Directly under this floating div element there should be an element that matches the width of the body elements clientWidth and the height of the body elements clientHeight, which you can refer to as a screen.  Give the screen a background of black with an opacity of 25%.  The screen will intercept all clicks since it is layered over the rest of the page, except for the modal which is layered above it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/Javascript">
        function loading()
        {
            var sss = document.getElementById('back');
            sss.style.opacity="0.20";
            return true;
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #set {
        width:350px;
        height:350px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background:#ccc;
        color:#000;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="back">
    <div id="set">
            <h1>This div you have to view.</h1>
        <input type="button" onclick="loading();" value="Button"/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

You can also use jquery for this...... All the best..